# What are difference of four different Linux version R?

Tags: linux, r

I want to install R into Linux, which version of R should I choose, Debian, Redhat,suse and Ubuntu? Please give advice?Thanks

Comment: R is the same, just choose whatever distribution you're most comfortable with.

Answer (score 1):

You will chose the version intended for the version of Linux you are installing on. If you are not installing on one of the four named versions, I would recommend downloading a source bundle and compiling yourself.